# How to identify syllable border in a word based on spelling alone?

Tags: spelling

I want to know what (if there are any) are the rules for identifying the syllables and their borders in a word based only on its spelling and not its pronunciation or IPA. I know syllable is a phonetic feature and not a orthographic one, but since German language has a high correspondence between the two, are there a set of rules to identify the syllable and its border in a word based on the spelling of the word alone.

Comment: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/worttrennung

Comment: While any occurance of *ngstschw* in the middle of a word can only be hyphenated *ngst-schw*, pure spelling will not help you hyphenate *Druckerzeugnis* and may allow for unfortunate (but technically correct) hyphenation of *Urinstinkt*

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple rules to identify syllable border(s) in a word based on spelling.
Note that you need to know german prefix and suffix.

**For every Word**

- A Syllable will always contain a vowel (a,e,i,o,u)

**For one syllable Words**

- I think this depends on the sound of the word, but in a sense you can assume that if none of the rules below apply, it could be a one syllable word

**Words with more than one syllable**

- A single vowel never gets seperated from the Word. *Fisch-e* would be wrong
- "tz" and "st" always indicate a border. *put-zen*
- "ch", "sch", "ck", "eu", "ei", "ai", "äu" always stay together. *ba-cken*
- "ß" transforms to ss and will result in a border between. *grüs-sen*
- Two consonants result in a border. *Af-fe*
- A prefix indicates a border. *ver-laufen*
- If a suffix starts with a vowel, the border happens in front of the previous consonant. *Zei-tung* (-ung being the suffix)

**Words made of multiple words (e.g. *Hausaufgaben*)**

- A new word indicates a border. *Haus-aufgaben-heft*
- Borders in subwords are found like its an individual word. *Haus-auf-ga-ben-heft*

I took them from https://praxistipps.focus.de/silbentrennung-regeln-und-funktionsweise-einfach-erklaert_99467 and translated them too english.

**Note that this will find NOT every border in every word as some words require the sound of the word to find syllable**

Comment: *ß* does not transform – either it stays as it is, e.g. [*grü-ßen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/grueszen), or it is *ss* from the beginning (in Switzerland), but I don’t know how the Swiss hyphenate it.